# nested two phase commit (nested/tree 2PC) in java?

Tags: java, jta, distributed-transactions, xa

I have read in wikipedia about the nested two phase commit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol#Tree_two-phase_commit_protocol) which allows one to have a tree of two phase commits.

Is there something available in java for this and does this work with JTA implementations?

Comment: Curious: why do you need support for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there are several transaction manager implemented in Java. If interested see for example http://narayana.io